# how to show boundary of either open or closed set is nowhere dense.

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

how to show boundary of either open or closed set is nowhere dense.

i think we need to use baire category thm?

countable intersection of dense, closed set is once again a dense, closed (and nonempty)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** use the expression
$$
\partial A = \bar A - \text{int }A
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use mookid's hint. Suppose A is closed and its  boundary contains an open $V$.  Then $V$ is in A but not in the interior of A! Impossible, since???? (definition of the interior of a set...)